# Combining Rows by Code

Tags: sql-server

Data set:

```
  CREATE TABLE Returned(
  Code varchar(20) not null, 
  RUnits int not null, 
  RCost int not null, 
  RPrice int not null, 
  RDate date not null);


  Insert into Returned(Code, Runits, rcost, rprice, rdate)
  values
  ('ORANGES123', 10, 200, 500, '2017-04-01'), 
  ('BANANAS123', 15, 350, 900, '2017-04-01'),
  ('APPLES123', 7, 234, 756, '2017-04-01'),
    ('ORANGES123', 10, 200, 500, '2017-04-02'), 
  ('BANANAS123', 15, 350, 900, '2017-04-02'),
  ('APPLES123', 7, 234, 756, '2017-04-02');



  CREATE TABLE Cancelled(
  Code varchar(20) not null, 
  CUnits int not null, 
  CCost int not null, 
  CPrice int not null, 
  CDate date not null
  );

    Insert into Cancelled(Code, Cunits, Ccost, Cprice, Cdate)
  values
  ('ORANGES123', 3, 100, 200, '2017-04-01'), 
  ('BANANAS123', 5, 243, 500, '2017-04-01'),
  ('APPLES123', 10, 235, 537, '2017-04-01'),
  ('ORANGES123', 3, 100, 200, '2017-04-02'), 
  ('BANANAS123', 5, 243, 500, '2017-04-02'),
  ('APPLES123', 10, 235, 537, '2017-04-02');
```

Sqlfiddle here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f10634

Background:

I have 2 tables. A table for returns, and a table for cancels. I want to get a summation over the past week of the total number of units/cost/price for a given item code. For example, from the sqlfiddle, ORANGES123, I want my query to return:

```
ItemCode  , TotalReturnedUnits, TotalReturnedCost, TotalReturnedPrice,TotalCancelledUnits, TotalCancelledCost, TotalCancelledPrice 
ORANGES123,                 20,               400,               1000,                  6,                200,                 400
```

This seems simple but for some reason when I'm doing an inner join by ItemCode between my two tables in SQL Server, Units between the Cancelled and Returned tables are being combined and the counts are being cross-polluted between Returned/Cancelled.

I feel like I'm missing something very simple.

Any help would be appreciated.

The actual query I'm working with is here. I tried to model the sqlfiddle as close as possible:

```
SELECT sales.Code AS Code,
       sales.Quantity AS QtyReturned,
       price.WghtAvgCost * sales.Quantity AS ReturnedCost,
       price.CurrentPrice * sales.Quantity AS ReturnedPrice,
       orders.CancelledUnits, 
       orders.CancelledCost,
       orders.CancelledPrice,
       price.CurrentPriceType AS PriceType
FROM salesTable sales
     INNER JOIN costPriceTable price ON sales.Code= price.Code
                                                  AND (sales.BusinessDate BETWEEN price.StartDate AND price.EndDate)
                                                  AND sales.LocationId = price.LocationId
    INNER JOIN  ordersTable orders
       ON sales.Code= orders.Code
```

Comment: Can we see your select statement please?

Comment: Can you include your query?

Comment: If it was me, I'd have just one table, instead of two.

Comment: The current table design can't be changed due to existing processes that use them.

Comment: So use a UNION.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with this - I think you can figure the rest out...

```
SELECT *, 'returned' source FROM returned
 UNION ALL
SELECT *, 'cancelled' FROM cancelled;
+------------+--------+-------+--------+------------+-----------+
| Code       | RUnits | RCost | RPrice | RDate      | source    |
+------------+--------+-------+--------+------------+-----------+
| ORANGES123 |     10 |   200 |    500 | 2017-04-01 | returned  |
| BANANAS123 |     15 |   350 |    900 | 2017-04-01 | returned  |
| APPLES123  |      7 |   234 |    756 | 2017-04-01 | returned  |
| ORANGES123 |     10 |   200 |    500 | 2017-04-02 | returned  |
| BANANAS123 |     15 |   350 |    900 | 2017-04-02 | returned  |
| APPLES123  |      7 |   234 |    756 | 2017-04-02 | returned  |
| ORANGES123 |      3 |   100 |    200 | 2017-04-01 | cancelled |
| BANANAS123 |      5 |   243 |    500 | 2017-04-01 | cancelled |
| APPLES123  |     10 |   235 |    537 | 2017-04-01 | cancelled |
| ORANGES123 |      3 |   100 |    200 | 2017-04-02 | cancelled |
| BANANAS123 |      5 |   243 |    500 | 2017-04-02 | cancelled |
| APPLES123  |     10 |   235 |    537 | 2017-04-02 | cancelled |
+------------+--------+-------+--------+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me far enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a joined query to achieve this, follow the same structure for your cancellations as well.

```
JOIN
(SELECT 
Code, sum(RUnits) as TotalReturnedUnits, sum(RCost) as TotalReturnedCost, 
sum(RPrice) as TotalReturnedPrice
from Returned
where 

--parameterised dates can be used
--RDate between @Start and @End

group by Code
)returns
ON salesTable.Code = returns.Code
```